# How can make alt text rotates through the alt text of the images on the page showing one after another every few seconds??? using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

this all I got have so far somebody please help!!! I know I'm on the right path by using a timer my code just don't seen to be running it was working before when I had the event listeners but I just want to loop the alt text to display the all the different text.

```
///jquery code
$(function() {
    function eventHandler(event) {
        let images = $("#images");
        let imagesalt = images.text(this).attr("alt");




    }
    setTimeout(eventHandler, 2000);




});
```

Comment: Please tell your problem more briefly

Comment: For that you may use the setInterval(eventHandler, 2000); this will execute the eventHandler function after every 2 seconds interval

Comment: @Rishab I tried using the setInterval but it was not working either so I think my problem is inside the function.

Comment: @Ibnelaiq so what I what I want to do is a make image viewer that displays the alt text as soon and it loads and keeps looping throughout the different alt text. but every time that I test it it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: So you want to display random alt text of image on hover.

Comment: @Ibnelaiq not exactly I want it to go in order from the first image to the last image and loop like as soon as it loads without using any event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through all the images you should use the class selector instead of id.

You can use $.each() JQuery method to loop the images based on class selector as shown below in sample code:

For On load event use the

```
$(function(){
  // after all DOM element is loaded this will execute
});
```

**#CODE:**

```js
$(function(){
    // using class selector and looping through it
    $(".my_images").each(function(index,value){
          var imagesalt = $(this).text(this).attr("alt");
          console.log(imagesalt);
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="my_images" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Smiley 1"> 
<img class="my_images" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Smiley 2"> 
<img class="my_images" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Smiley 3"> 
<img class="my_images" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Smiley 4">
```